# Transfer MetaData from JSON to sharepoint column

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, powershell-2.0, metadata-extractor

We have sharepoint site where meta data (doc id, auther, and modified date are stored in json. Now we need get it in sharepoint columns.

I tried pnp powershell command

[System.Net.WebClient]::new().DownloadString($path) | ConvertFrom-Json

but throws an error "Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

I then run

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 and checked my permission level. All looks good , But same error.

I am happy to try msgraph if that is more easy, but fairy new and appreciate if any one can share any info or suggest a web site.